# Mace allowed in checked bags on Avianca flights leaving the USA?

Tags: air-travel, luggage

It seems a small container (under 4 oz) of Mace is allowed in checked baggage per the US TSA.  But the Avianca site says it prohibits pepper sprays.  It is not clear to me if Avianca is referring to carry-on baggage concerning this prohibition, or also includes checked baggage.

Does anyone have experience leaving the USA with a small container of pepper spray in checked baggage on Avianca?

Comment: Airlines have their own rules in addition to the TSA

Comment: @Midavalo Does Avianca do the screening of baggage in US airports or the TSA?  Does the TSA enforce Avianca policy?

Comment: From a practical point, if the mace is in checked luggage then I can't see how Avianca would be able to tell it apart from any other small spray bottle that was in checked luggage.   The bigger question is if Mace is legal in your destination, as it is not legal in all counties.

Comment: I'd also take a look at [Are aerosol cans allowed and safe, in checked luggage?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/35490/6188) about aerosols in general

Comment: @PeterM, there are also places where mace in general may be legal, but only if it has been officially inspected/certified as safe. It may well be that an otherwise identical can, lacking the certificate, becomes illegal to own.

Answer (score 3):

Avianca, on its website, clearly lists [a number of items which are not permitted in checked baggage](https://ayuda.avianca.com/hc/en-us/articles/13083117125403-What-items-are-not-allowed-in-my-baggage-), including:

> - Disabling elements: Self-defence gases, pepper sprays or irritant substances.

If your spray falls into this category, then it is not allowed on Avianca flights in checked baggage.