# Is it possible to buy Mace spray in Guayaquil, Ecuador?

Tags: ecuador

It seems that I will not be able to take Mace spray into Ecuador on Avianca: [Mace allowed in checked bags on Avianca flights leaving the USA?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/182055/mace-allowed-in-checked-bags-on-avianca-flights-leaving-the-usa)

The alternative is to buy it after arrival.

What type of store in Guayaquil sells Mace or other pepper spray?

Comment: This is now a shopping question, not a travel question

Comment: @Midavalo "Where can I buy Mace?" would indeed be a shopping question,but "Can I buy it?" has a perfectly objective answer of "No, it's illegal to possess in Ecuador." (Yes,it might perhaps be possible to buy it illegally, but TSE typically does not discuss or condone such options.)

Comment: @TooTea which is why this question, which asks "_Where in Guayaquil is it possible to buy Mace or other pepper spray?_" is off topic

Comment: @Midavalo Oh,I missed that the body of the question contains something else than what's in the title. Then the body can just be edited instead of closing the question unnecessarily. Knowing that Mace is illegal in Ecuador is IMHO useful for travelers and thus on topic.

Comment: @Midavalo The link in the answer below says that pepper spray is now legal.  Are you differentiating between CN and pepper spray?

Comment: @Yehuda_NYC I am saying that asking for where to buy things is off topic

Comment: @Midavalo You wrote "Knowing that Mace is illegal in Ecuador is IMHO useful" but the answer sites a URL that says it is now legal.  Meanwhile, I'll modify the question

Comment: @Yehuda_NYC no I didn't, you're quoting someone else

Comment: @Yehuda_NYC my answer does **not** cite that Mace is legal. It cites that certain pepper sprays are legal, while Mace can be subject to confiscation and penalties.

Answer (score 5):

This website
[Ecuador firearms laws and arms that are legal to carry and own in Ecuador](https://cuencahighlife.com/ecuador-gun-laws-arms-that-are-legal-to-carry-and-or-own-in-ecuador/) says

> **Pepper Spray & Mace.**
>
> You do not need a special permit to carry Pepper Spray in Ecuador as a weapon of self-defense, because its carrying and responsible use is permitted all throughout Ecuador. The only pepper spray allowed in the country is the one that contains a value equal to or less than 1.3% of capsaicin (that generally being in line with industry standards for the production and distribution of Pepper Spray products), as it’s considered a non-lethal weapon.
>
> However, Mace, which is generally considered as being akin to or the same as Tear Gas, can be subject to confiscation and penalties, as technically Tear Gas is only meant/supposed to be in the possession of and/or utilized by the Ecuadorian Police and Ecuadorian Military (as evidenced in past unruly and violent protests that occurred within Ecuador).

Also [Ecuadorian President okays right to bear arms and pepper spray](https://en.mercopress.com/2023/04/03/ecuadorian-president-okays-right-to-bear-arms-and-pepper-spray) has

> In addition, the use of pepper spray for personal defense is authorized and the production, registration, and possession of handmade weapons were banned.

I don't know where you can obtain pepper spray.

---

To be clear: tourists can carry/use certain pepper sprays, but Mace is not allowed. So no, you must not attempt to buy Mace in Ecuador.